# Angular stepped progress bar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have  recently started working on angular and I am trying  to add progress bar to my angular code but I am unable to get how to do this. The progress bar which I want is as shown in attached image[image: angular progress bar image]::

How to add progress bar shown in attached image in header of the page using angular?

Comment: First you've to make the UI and after that you've to create a component which has only the above step bar. You have to maintain the state with enum or numbers and separate color/image if the state is active. And this child component you've to add it in parent component where you will be showing different views based on the active state value.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? As I am new to angular  that's why I am very cofused

Comment: checkout https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview . or just a simple google search on `angular stepper example` would give you sample projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in so many ways.
1. You can do it with CSS by making a similar shape using https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/  and use different two different class for the state.

2. You can use two different color image of the same shape and one is for default and another one is for after changing the progress. and enable the 2nd image on every success step.

I am just telling you the logic.

Comment: do you have any example for  this. It would be helpful for me to understand

Comment: I want to do it using angular

Comment: Hey Man!! why don't you try angular material?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to hide the default stepper header

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Use `EventEmitter<StepperSelectionEvent>` to listen to the stepper changes and implement your own progress bar UI / component.